# GML and nullable Foreign keys

Tags: xml, xsd, foreign-keys, nullable, xsd-validation

In my **XSD** schema there is a foreign key which is nullable. When I create GML related to that schema, validator says:

> Cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'foreignKey_admKucniBroj_zgrada' With Value 'null' Not Found For Identity Constraint Of Element 'KAT_CadastreFeatureCollection'.. Line '57363', Column '37'

FK from schema:

```
    <xsd:keyref name="foreignKey_admKucniBroj_zgrada" refer="fgu:primaryKey_katZgrada">
        <xsd:selector xpath=".//fgu:ADM_Kucni_Broj"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="fgu:zgrada"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
```

And part of object's definition:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ADM_KucniBrojType" final="#all">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="fgu:KatastarskiGeoObjektType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="zgrada" type="fgu:oidType" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Does anyone knows what's happening, what's wrong?

Comment: You appear to have a reference with a null value; the validator is looking for the matching key, which would be a key with a null value, and not finding it.  Which part of this is puzzling to you?

Comment: I dont understand how can I have null as reference when I have reference to primary key of non-empty table? And how can even FK be a nullable?

Comment: Please post your XML. Are you sure you don't mistaken empty field/null for `xsi:nil="true"`? What do you have in your XML?

Comment: How can you have a null reference under these circumstances?  Good question.  If you provide a minimum complete working example, it may be possible to figure it out; without one, no one can tell.